# Authentication of Custom User Model in Django 3.0

Tags: python, django, model

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to make a User Authentication of my Custom User Model. My model was created successfully and a `'createsuperuser'` command inserts new users in it. I can then log in with these accounts and everything works. But I want to be able to insert new users from my Sign Up form.  I followed the steps from Django documentation, however, it doesn't insert new users. It does not give me any error and therefore I would appreciate any help.

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
}
]
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
     class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'full_name', 'country', 'city', 'birthday', 'language', 'email')


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

    class Register(CreateView):
        form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
        template_name = 'movies_app/register.html'
```

**movie_project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('movies_app/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('movies_app.urls', namespace='movies_app')),
]
```

**movies_app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import Register

app_name = 'movies_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register/', Register.as_view(), name='Register')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the your user in views.py after any post request you are getting.

Try below code:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Or you can follow below URL for more details.

> https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html